# Firebase Signin with email and password require SHA Key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I don't want any app rather than my APK to use my firebase database. So is there any way by that I can disable sign-in with email and password if the SHA footprint doesn't match with the one saved in firebase console?

I think sign-in with the phone will restrict access if sha1 is not saved in the console. Can I do the same for email and password?

Or is there any other way?

Comment: others app cant use your database if they dont have the google-services.json inside their project, you are worried if someone steals your sha-1 to be able to see your database?

Comment: But they can still decompile, edit some codes and generate new apk file right ?? How to prevent apks that are edited to modify database.